# Does Intense Debate query my database?

Tags: wordpress, comments

I'm thinking about implementing [Intense Debate](http://intensedebate.com/) in my Wordpress site.
I know that ID stores comments in its own database and in the wordpress database.

I haven't understood if this software query my database for comments when a page are requested or if it query his own system. In the second case I could have some benefits on the server-load size of my website...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted the Intense Debate support and they answered me. Intense Debate queries only IB database so your database will not be touched ;)